# Google Drive API "Save to Drive" multiple files

Tags: javascript, php, html, download, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use the Googe Drive Save button on my webpage. The official documentation says, that `data-src="//example.com/path/to/myfile.pdf"` represents the file I want to save to Drive. What if I want to save multiple files, but don't want to add multiple buttons?

I tryed to add multiple `data-src:` but of course, it was not working.

I know, that I can save multiple files in one ZIP file, but is it possible to save multiple files once without zipping them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `"Save to Drive"` button cannot be used to save multiple files to Drive. You should add a button per file. While this is not made explicit in the docs, the rules for adding a button are quite clear and don't allow much flexibility:

- [Add the "Save to Drive" button to a page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/savetodrive#add_the_save_to_drive_button_to_a_page)

#### Workaround:

If you want to add several files to Drive through a single button, you could attach your button to an event (an [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick), or what have you) which would fire a function that would call [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) for each of the files you want to save to Drive.

Check the referenced `Browser Quickstart` if you need indications on how to handle the OAuth process / how to call the API method.

#### Reference:

- [Add the "Save to Drive" button](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/savetodrive)
- [Drive API: Browser Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js)
- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)